# Is it possible to use VirtualFile as HTML Template provider? And How?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

need your help!

I hope title is descriptive but here is details

Lets say we have 5 web applications, and lets say they are done with 5 distinct frameworks. One of those is using playframework. Now, since rebranding all five websites will take tremendous time we came to idea to host one layout template as HTML page which will contain <% doLayout %> play tag in it.

We need way to use this layout as it is part of play application source code. Now I read API docs and found VirtualFile class ([VirtualFile API Docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.1/play/vfs/VirtualFile.html)). Since docs are pretty brief and I cant tell what is purpose of this class from docs, but I see it contains features which could be useful for my case...

Below is the same class in action but in .NET. I did such integration while ago but now I need it in playframework too. Also note that example on link below is served from zip archive, but with VirtualPathProviders you can serve template from anywhere
[Virtualizing Access to Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479502.aspx)

Any help is appreciated, tho, solution doesn't need to include VirtualFile, but it have to be plug and play.

Note: We are using playframework 1.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem, but not with virtual file class. It can be dan if I create custom tag in play which will replace `extend` tag in my views.

If you look at play source code you can find how existing works
[FastTags class, line 319](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/FastTags.java)

```
public static void _extends(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out, ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
    try {
        if (!args.containsKey("arg") || args.get("arg") == null) {
            throw new TemplateExecutionException(template.template, fromLine, "Specify a template name", new TagInternalException("Specify a template name"));
        }
        String name = args.get("arg").toString();
        if (name.startsWith("./")) {
            String ct = BaseTemplate.currentTemplate.get().name;
            if (ct.matches("^/lib/[^/]+/app/views/.*")) {
                ct = ct.substring(ct.indexOf("/", 5));
            }
            ct = ct.substring(0, ct.lastIndexOf("/"));
            name = ct + name.substring(1);
        }
        BaseTemplate.layout.set((BaseTemplate) TemplateLoader.load(name));
    } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
        throw new TemplateNotFoundException(e.getPath(), template.template, fromLine);
    }
}
```

I just need to use overloaded method `TemplateLoader.load(String, String)` which accepts template as string (comparing to filename in original implementation) and then set it to 
`BaseTemplate.layout.set(...)` method. Of course, first I need to get template from remote server through HTTP request.